# Кавычки в переменной - подстановка и условия

Tags: windows, bat

У меня есть переменная заданная следующим образом:

```
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:"%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml"
```

Обратите внимание, что %CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml обернуто в двойные кавычки, т.к. в дальнейшем эта переменная будет передана java приложению.

Следующий if я не могу менять:

```
if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" ...
```

Тут возникает ошибка, т.к. при подстановке cmd считает, что была открыта первая кавычка, далее он ищет закрывающую, первая которая будет на его пути это ...=file:**"**...

В итоге возникает одна из следующих ситуаций:

1. Если заданы кавычки, то if падает (еще раз замечу, что этот if я не могу менять)
2. Убрать кавычки. Тогда при передаче java приложению неверно понимается параметр, т.к. пробел является разделителем. (а путь может быть с пробелами)

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ изменить определение переменной так, чтобы и if сработал и переменная понималась правильно.

Comment: `Следующий if я не могу менять` Совсем или по смыслу? обычно в качестве квоттеров строкового литерала используют сравнительно безопасные символы, а не двойную кавычку.

Comment: @Akina ну, решение через изменение if я знаю, но по некоторым причинам хочу обойти это.

Comment: решение через изменение if: 

      if not defined LOGGING_MANAGER

Comment: conf\logback.xml"" - здесь две двойные?!

Comment: @AlbertFomin извиняюсь, там опечатка

Comment: Почему вы проверяете `if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" …`? Если бы было определено даже и `set "CATALINA_HOME="` потом `"%LOGGING_MANAGER%"` бы было `"-Djuli-logback.configurationFile=file:"\conf\logback.xml""` однако никогда `""`